# Parsing NMEA data with strange timestamp for a time-series plot

Tags: python, parsing, nmea

I have an NMEA data that looks like this:

```
13:07:46.380: <- $WIMDA,30.0911,I,1.0190,B,11.8,C,,,78.3,,8.1,C,70.4,T,68.0,M,8.9,N,4.6,M*59

13:07:46.427: <- $TIROT,-5.9,A*1A

13:07:46.552: <- $YXXDR,C,,C,WCHR,C,,C,WCHT,C,,C,HINX,P,1.0179,B,STNP*45

13:07:46.630: <- $GPVTG,184.3,T,181.9,M,0.0,N,0.0,K,D*29

13:07:46.708: <- $YXXDR,A,1.5,D,PTCH,A,-0.5,D,ROLL*71

13:07:46.770: <- $WIMWV,314.7,R,9.1,N,A*2A

13:07:46.848: <- $GPZDA,131718.60,01,02,2019,00,00*64

13:07:47.020: <- $GPGGA,131718.70,2918.7847,N,09449.0397,W,2,10,1.1,9.2,M,-26.5,M,,*52

13:07:47.332: <- $WIMDA,30.0940,I,1.0191,B,11.8,C,,,78.3,,8.1,C,71.4,T,69.0,M,7.8,N,4.0,M*54

13:07:47.379: <- $TIROT,-21.1,A*24
```

I want to extract the time and the data from the lines containing $WIMWV and $WIMDA (using python), the data I need is in bold:

**13:07:46.380**: <- $WIMDA,30.0911,I,**1.0190**,B,11.8,C,,,78.3,,8.1,C,70.4,T,68.0,M,8.9,N,4.6,M*59

**13:07:46.770**: <- $WIMWV,**314.7**,R,**9.1**,N,A*2A

What is a good way to do this? since the separation of the time step is strange I don't know how to extract what I need for a time-series plot.

Thank you!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And BTW the interval is not strange. NMEA message usually come at a fixed intetval, like every second. With maybe a slight offset cause by the serial interface.

Comment: I'm trying to use pynmea2, but because of the timestamp, I can't. I will probably have to do it manually but I don't have an idea how to start

Comment: You have to get rid if the timestamps they are not part of the messages. Use the `GPZDA` field instead.

Comment: But I need the timestamp to build a time series!

Comment: As edited above: the format has its own time reference messages. And your timestamps seem to be 10 min off.

Comment: Where do you see it? and how I can get rid of the timestamps?

Comment: You should read the format specifications and write some code. If you get stuck tell us where.